# What is the meaning of the different links in the binomial family of a GLM model in R?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution

In the help of the glm command in R, I read

> the binomial family the links logit, probit, cauchit, (corresponding to 
>   logistic, normal and Cauchy CDFs respectively) log and cloglog
>   (complementary log-log)

What are the difference between the "normal", Cauchy, log, cloglog models? When should I use them? Are these ONLY referring to different the error models? Anyone can provide Examples or recommendation to prefer one over the other?

Comment: I'm asking exactly about those families not covered in the "Duplicated" you found. I only found some references to the cloglog function, but nothing about the other families...